# How to Show line numbers in WinEdt?, BY DEFAULT

Tags: winedt

You can active de show number lines, but ...

How to chow number lines by default?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it´s possible!! after asking Adriana/Alex (WinEdt author)

"Yes. Options –> Preferences| Appearance.
 Click on the Help button for details"

As you can see in the iamge.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Open the `Options interface` and select `Bookmarks.ini`. Add the  `TeX` mode to the line `LINE_NUMBERS_MODE_FILTER=`:

[image]

and click on `Load Current Script`.

Comment: let me mentioned that this works only for new documents. for existing documents you still need activate line numbering manually.

Comment: the @Zarko is no possible active numebering lines ofr existing AND new documents?

Comment: You can activate it manually for existing documents. You only have to do it  once. You also can ask Alex if something can be done writing  at support@winedt.com. He is very reactive.

Comment: @Bernard ok. I´m going to ask Alex.